# Nokia 5800 - USB Tethering

Tags: windows-7, usb-modem, nokia-pc-suite, nokia-ovi-suite

I have a Windows 7 PC without any WIFI cards and a Nokia 5800 XM without a sim card. I want to connect this pc to my home wifi network and so i was thinking to give this 5800 a chance.

My goal here is to connect the phone to wifi and use it on pc.

What i already did,

1. Installed Nokia Suite and drivers
2. Connected Phone to PC via USB cable
3. Tried setting up USB dial up modem
4. Tried searching on the internet

Somebody help...

Comment: Although Symbian can, in general, do just about anything, I doubt it can do this. Even if it could, a cheap WiFi adapter would be a lot faster.

Comment: I could use another phone, but just wanted to know if i could make use of this phone. I don't use this phone any other way :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the term 'Reverse-tethering'. This is where you share you mobile internet connection with a PC. Modern phones can do this over bluetooth, usb or Wifi.

I've checked your model of phone and it appears it is not supported on this operating system (Symbian).

Comment: No, reverse tethering would be giving the phone access to the PC’s Internet uplink.

Comment: That is what normal tethering is @DanielB

Comment: [No it’s not?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering)